# WPF Combobox binding to dictionary - wrong value returned

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a very simple use case:
a property with `NotifyPropertyChanged()` event, a `Dictionary<string, string>` with some static data and a combobox.

The CB is defined like so:

```
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllThings}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" 
SelectedValuePath="Key" SelectedItem="{Binding Thing, Mode=TwoWay, 
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

The VM contains:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> AllThings { get; set; }= new Dictionary<string, string>{["a"] = "b"};

    private string thing;

    public string Thing
    {
      get
      {
        return this.thing;
      }
      set
      {
        if (this.thing != value)
        {
          this.thing = value;
          this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
      }
    }
```

When the user selects the value, instead of "b" i am getting a strange looking string:
`[a, b]` in the `value` inside the `Thing` setter.

I want to display "b" and store "a" in the "Thing".

*UPD* Likewise, setting the `Thing` to `b` does not result in `b` being selected in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem.  The Item is the key/value pair in the dictionary which is not what you want.